# How to add an anchor <a> in KTOR?

Tags: ktor

How can we declare a `<a>` in KTOR's HTML DSL? I know there's a tag like `a { href = "example.com" }`, but I can't set its label. So, it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Enum-attributes) you can get the following example:

```
a(target = "myCustomValue") { + "..." }
```

so for your case, this would be:

```
a(href= "example.com") { + "example.com" }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @maio290! I was looking for something like that in https://ktor.io/servers/features/templates/html-dsl.html 